# How to debug PDF files on Android?

Tags: android, pdf, ghostscript

I'm working on an Android app that's already on production stage. The app generates PDF reports. Lately we've been receiving complaints from customers about not being able to open a PDF file. I've found many free online tools to check the PDF, but I'm receiving stuff like 'unable to process due to PDF error'.

I found a usefull tool online: Ghostscript.

It turns out that the corrupted PDF files generated have an invalid xref entry in the table. Does someone know how to detect it on Android programatically, so I can retry the generation process or seomthing? Or is it possible to fix it programatically?

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up using was [iText7](https://itextpdf.com/es/products/itext-7) for debugging purposes, and [pdfBox](https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android) for production purposes, to detect when the PDF generated was corrupted, and leave the responsability to the user to generate the PDF all over.